# Ranking using XGBoost Model from xgboost package

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, xgboost

Is there any way to apply the XG Boost model using the XG Boost package for pairwise ranking?
I have created the training features using the below code

```
#input dictionary
d1 = {"america":{"norway":[1.1,1.2,1.3], "brazil":[2.1,2.3,2.2],"africa":[1.3,1.2,1.5]},
  "europe":{"africa":[2.1,2.2,2.3], "brazil":[4.1,4.2,4.3],"fluorida":[5.1,5.2,5.3]},
  "australia":{"norway":[1.1,1.8,1.9],"brazil":[4.2,4.3,4.4],"fluorida":[5.1,5.2,5.3]}}
# convert dictionary to DataFrame
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient="index")
feature = dataframe.fillna(0)
```

Training Features which are stored in feature variable:

```
              norway          brazil         africa       fluorida
  america   [1.1, 1.2, 1.3] [2.1, 2.3, 2.2] [1.3, 1.2, 1.5] 0
  australia [1.1, 1.8, 1.9] [4.2, 4.3, 4.4] 0   [5.1, 5.2, 5.3]
  europe    0   [4.1, 4.2, 4.3] [2.1, 2.2, 2.3] [5.1, 5.2, 5.3]
```

I have created the training labels using the below code:

```
#dictionary for training labels
d2 = {"america":{"norway":1, "brazil":1,"africa":1},
  "europe":{"africa":1, "brazil":1,"fluorida":1},
  "australia":{"norway":1,"brazil":1,"fluorida":1}}
# convert dictionary to DataFrame
dataframe_t = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2, orient="index")
label = dataframe_t.fillna(0)
```

Training label which are stored in label variable

```
                     norway brazil  africa  fluorida
     america          1.0         1       1.0   0.0
     australia        1.0         1       0.0   1.0
     europe           0.0         1       1.0   1.0
```

I have applied XGBoost using the below line of code

```
import xgboost as xgb
model =  xgb.XGBModel(max_depth=1, booster='gbtree', objective='rank:pairwise')
model.fit(feature, label)
```

I am not able to apply XGboost using the above line of code? Is there any way to apply XGBoost for ranking on the above mentioned data?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The Error is:
ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.
                Did not expect the data types in fields norway, brazil, africa, fluorida

Comment: Exactly, if you see the values, it's 1.0 for Norway and 1 for Brazil. So try making it as same data type either int or float.